# Does the existence of solutions of $P(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\mathfrak{m}^n}$ for all $n$ gives a solution of $P(x)=0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, axiom-of-choice, local-rings

Let $A$ be a complete local noetherian ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Let $P(X_1,...,X_d)$ be a polynomial in $d$ variables and coefficients in $A$ and assume that the equation
$$P(x_1,...,x_d)\equiv 0\pmod{\mathfrak{m}^n}$$
admits a solution for all $n\geq 1$. Can I conclude that the equation $P(x_1,...,x_d)=0$ admits a solution in $A^d$?

The problem lies in the fact that it is not clear how we can find a compatible system of solutions.

Many thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, there are one-variable polynomials with integer coefficients with zeroes modulo $m$ for all $m$ but no integer zeroes.

Comment: If you mean $m$ running over maximal ideals, this isn’t helping I guess...

Comment: I think if $A/m$ is finite you can get something: a root in $(A/m^n)^d$ is in particular a root in $(A/m)^d$. Since there are infinitely many $n$, at least one root in $(A/m)^d$ is hit infinitely many times. But if it's hit infinitely many times, then I can take one antecedent in $(A/m^2)^d$ which is also hit infinitely many times, and then go up the ladder this way. (I'm guessing you know about Hensel's lemma in the simple root case ?)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Indeed. I think it's König's Lemma.

Comment: If $y$ is the limit of your convergent sequence, doesn't it imply $P(y)=0$ mod every power of the maximal ideal and thus by Krull's intersection theorem, actually zero?

Comment: @Mohan how do you prove that the sequence converges ?

Comment: A sequence $y_m$ such that $y_{m+1}-y_m\in \mathfrak{m}^m$ is Cauchy.

Comment: @Mohan Again, how do you know that y_{m+1}-y_m\in\mathfrak{m} ? I do not make this assumption, and that is the tricky part.

Comment: What does this question have to do with the axiom of choice (and specifically with the acceptable usage of [tag:axiom-of-choice] on this website)?